# Create a variable based on factors found by applying grepl over multiple columns

Tags: r, apply, grepl

I have got the following data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 10), age = seq(45,54),
Diag1 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag2 = sample(c("D123", "", "A155"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag3 = sample(c("G123", "H123", "I123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag4 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag5 = sample(c("J123", "K123", ""), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag6 = sample(c("", "N123", "O123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag7 = sample(c("P123", "Q123", "R123"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I am looking for all id's with a factor that starts with "A1" in one of the columns Diag1-7

1) I know how to search the complete data frame for one particular factor:

```
y <- Data[apply(Data,1,function(x) {"A123" %in% x}),]
```

2) I know how to search for a pattern within one column:

```
x <- Data[grepl("A1", Data$Diag1),]
```

A) I would like to use grepl in the same way as in 1) on all the columns Diag1-Diag7.

B) If possible I would like to create a new variable called "result" which contains a 1 if there is a "A1" in the row and 0 if there is no "A1" in the row.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A: You can easily use grepl on columns:

```
# select all columns except first two
y2 <- Data[apply(Data[-c(1,2),],2,function(x) {"A123" %in% x}),]
```

B:

```
Data$result <- as.numeric(apply(Data,1,function(x) {any(grepl("A1", x))}))
```

Is that what you wanted?

**Edit:** If `"A1"` needs to be at the begining, use `any(grepl("^A1.*", x))` as suggested below

Answer (score 1):

You need a regular expression. `"^A1.*"` means: if there is `A1` at the beginning of a string `^` followed by any number of other characters `.*`.

```
i <- apply(Data[3:9], 1, function(x) any(grepl("^A1.*", x)))
Data[i, ]

   id age Diag1 Diag2 Diag3 Diag4 Diag5 Diag6 Diag7
1   1  45  A123  D123  I123  B123        N123  R123
3   3  47  B123  A155  H123  B123        N123  Q123
4   4  48  C123        G123  A123  K123        P123
5   5  49  A123  A155  G123  C123  K123        Q123
7   7  51  C123  A155  G123  C123  J123        Q123
8   8  52  B123  A155  H123  A123  K123  N123  R123
10 10  54  A123  A155  H123  B123        N123  R123
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Data$count<-apply(Data,1,function(x)sum(grepl("^A1", x)))
Data
#   id age Diag1 Diag2 Diag3 Diag4 Diag5 Diag6 Diag7 count
#1   1  45  A123  D123  I123  B123        N123  R123     1
#2   2  46  B123  D123  G123  B123  K123  O123  P123     0
#3   3  47  B123  A155  H123  B123        N123  Q123     1
#4   4  48  C123        G123  A123  K123        P123     1
#5   5  49  A123  A155  G123  C123  K123        Q123     2
#6   6  50  C123        H123  C123              P123     0
#7   7  51  C123  A155  G123  C123  J123        Q123     1
#8   8  52  B123  A155  H123  A123  K123  N123  R123     2
#9   9  53  B123        I123  C123        N123  P123     0
#10 10  54  A123  A155  H123  B123        N123  R123     2
```

sorry: if you only want a 1/0 rather than a count:

```
Data$match<-apply(Data,1,function(x)as.integer(sum(grepl("^A1", x))>=1))
```